# Flask import CSV into pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I am attempting to create an app where the user could click a button to upload a CSV file into Pandas (hoping to do more in `pd` if I can get this work) and then display the data. Can someone give me a tip? I apologize in advance if its basic stuff, there isnt a lot of wisdom here:

`app.py`

```
from flask import Flask, make_response, request
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def form():
    return """
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Economizer Diagnostics</h1>

                <form action="/transform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="data_file" />
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
    """

@app.route('/transform', methods=["POST"])
def transform_view():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        df = pd.read_csv(request.files.get('file'), index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
        return render_template('simple.html',  tables=[df.to_html(classes='data')], titles=df.columns.values)
    return 'Oops, Try again something went wrong!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`simple.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

{% for table in tables %}
            {{titles[loop.index]}}
            {{ table|safe }}
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

When the code runs, I get an error about an invalid file path on the Pandas CSV file load.

FULL TRACE BACK:

```
File "C:\Users\benb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\benb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\benb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\benb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\benb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\benb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\benb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\benb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\benb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\benb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\Users\benb\Desktop\Flask\uploadTest3.py", line 28, in transform_view
df = pd.read_csv(request.files.get('file'))
File "C:\Users\benb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 702, in parser_f
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
File "C:\Users\benb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 413, in _read
filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression)
File "C:\Users\benb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 232, in get_filepath_or_buffer
raise ValueError(msg.format(_type=type(filepath_or_buffer)))
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'NoneType'>
```

Non software guy here any tips help. Thanks

Comment: What's the output of `request.files.get('file')` in this line:

`df = pd.read_csv(request.files.get('file'), index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)`

Comment: I am attempting to use a button where the user can upload a file thru a web browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
# data_file is the name of the file upload field
f = request.files['data_file']

# for security - stops a hacker e.g. trying to overwrite system files
filename = secure_filename(f.filename)

# save a copy of the uploaded file
f.save(filename)

# And then use it ...
df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
```

Comment: hello, is there anyway you could expand on your answer? Sorry I think I am not fully understanding, and I get an error `werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap.<locals>.newcls: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'file'` thank you

Comment: Ah, my mistake, got the name of your form field wrong - corrected post so `file` replaced with `data_file`