# TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response

Tags: python, pandas, flask

Im looking at the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56113219/flask-import-csv-into-pandas-df) but the answer isnt working.

This is my flask app code, where there is a button on into the HTML to browse for the csv file. Ultimately process the CSV file in pandas and print the highest value found in a column called `kW`

```
from flask import Flask, make_response, request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def form():
    return """
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Analysis</h1>

                <form action="/transform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="data_file" />
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
    """

@app.route('/transform', methods=["POST"])
def transform_view():
    # data_file is the name of the file upload field
    f = request.files['data_file']

    # for security - stops a hacker e.g. trying to overwrite system files
    filename = secure_filename(f.filename)

    # save a copy of the uploaded file
    f.save(filename)

    # And then use it ...
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)

    maxy = df.kW.max()
    print(maxy)
```

This is the simple.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

{% for table in tables %}
            {{titles[loop.index]}}
            {{ table|safe }}
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Any tips greatly appreciated... When I run the code (flask works) this will throw an error when the file is selected during the browse process.

`TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.`

Full traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\benb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__

return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

File "C:\Users\benb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app

response = self.handle_exception(e)

File "C:\Users\benb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "C:\Users\benb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise

raise value

File "C:\Users\benb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app

response = self.full_dispatch_request()

File "C:\Users\benb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1816, in full_dispatch_request

return self.finalize_request(rv)

File "C:\Users\benb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1831, in finalize_request

 [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] response = self.make_response(rv)

File "C:\Users\benb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1957, in make_response

'The view function did not return a valid response. The'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because your route `\transform` did return a valid response. This route must have a return statement. I am assuming that you want to load `simple.html` when this route is called, you can do the following things:

1. Import `render_template`:

```py
from flask import render_template
```

2. Use the return statement, in the route, like below:

```py
return render_template('simple.html')
```

Or just for dummy purpose you want this route to be executed without any error, then you can return like below:

```py
return 'Transformed!'
```

**Note:** This depends, what you actually want to return or what you want to render, when this route is executed. You can read the docs.

Comment: Thanks for the help im learning the web side... When I add the `return render_template` to the `app.route('/transform', methods=["POST"])` this throws an error... `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: simple.html`

Comment: Is it possible to view the `print(maxy)` in the browser? Thank you so much for posting to my question

Comment: Ohh, no worries, we are here to help you. `simple.html` must be under the `templates` directory of the project's root directory. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61847287/6635464).

Comment: Yep, you can easily show this on web browser, just by using `return maxy` in the rourte.

Comment: Also, you should make sure that, the return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, otherwise an exception will be thrown.

Comment: If I make `s = str(maxy)` how do I pass this to the head end? Do I need to incorporate something into the `simple.html`? Or would I need to make a totally different html file to view `s = str(maxy)`? Any tips or links to follow greatly appreciated

Comment: If I got you correctly, you want to display `maxy` in `simple.html`? Or I didn't get what do you mean by head node?

Comment: Sorry head end.. I meant web broswer. Yes view maxy in the browser after Pandas reads the CSV file...

Comment: If you want to view `maxy` in the web browser you can return like `return maxy`, like I said above. But, make sure that it's at least in string format.